# How do I add a custom NSView to an UI built with Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

What's the appropriate way to add an NSView, either using Objective-C or Swift, to an UI built with Interface Builder and stored as a xib file?

The environment is Cocoa and Mac OS X.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create custom views for that. You can subclass NSView and override drawRect . Please refer this link
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html

Comment: Unless I'm missing something from that link, I already have a NSView subclass, WKWebView. How do I put it in my Windows that I built with the Interface Builder?

Comment: You can drag and drop NSView to your window in IB. After that you can change that dropped view class from NSView to WKWebView.